# Selenium rc test fail with icheck jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-rc, icheck

I recently set up the jQuery plugin iCheck to improve checkbox and radio button of my application.
But my selenium test fail with this plugin. The plugin set the opacity of checkbox and radio buttons to 0. So selenium don't see them.I tried to set the opacity to 0.1 or 1 with a left position to -9999px to put elements out of the viewport.

Any solution?

Comment: Do you need to use [tag:Selenium-RC]? It has been deprecated for several years now.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately someone has wrote all test with selenium-rc. So my boss don't want to migrate to selenium web driver just for upgrade checkboxes.

Comment: Like I said ... Selenium RC has not been updated in several _years_; you will find that more and more things will no longer work. In any case, if you want any help with your problem, you will need to show code; see [Ask]. Based on the information you provided, we can only play 21 questions.